# Jquery load text from file into divs reload the page

Tags: jquery

I need to load in a div inside a modal a text form a file

"file.txt" located in the folder txt_files.

in my index i've this  jquery code

```
$('#modal-div').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var handler = $(event.relatedTarget); 
   var objData = handler.data();

   $('.div-for-text').load('path/to/file'+handler.data('contract'),function(){
        console.log('ok, done loading file');
    });
});
```

all wrapped in a `$(document).load(function(){});`

handler.data is a data-tag placed inside the button that load the modal. It contains the name of the file (file.txt).

and for final this is the div that need to be populated with the text data inside the modal:

```
<p class="div-for-text">
  <!--Load Text Here-->
 </p>
```

When i try to load the modal and trigger the function i see in my console ok, done loading file. But then all the page reloads and the div isn't populated.

I've tried to add a event.preventDefault() in the load callback function but it doesn't work.

Someone had the same problem?
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `event.preventDefault()` in your `.on()` callback function, not the `.load()` callback function code.

```
$('#modal-div').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   // HERE
   event.preventDefault()

   var handler = $(event.relatedTarget); 
   var objData = handler.data();

   $('.div-for-text').load('path/to/file'+handler.data('contract'),function(){
        console.log('ok, done loading file');
        // NOT HERE
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX to get the file and then update your `<div>` with it's contents. I haven't tested this but it should work:

```
$('#modal-div').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "file.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $(".div-for-text").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```